# web app & web services deployment together?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, service

I have a question about how to deploy website and its referenced web services from Dev environment to production environment by using some easy method.

Our deploy structure is basically like Desktop->Dev Server->Production Server.

Now, I create a web service (just named MailingServices for example), I deploy it Dev Server, the URL link should like: http://192.168.3.17:90/MailingServices.asmx

and then I deploy it to production server where link is probably like http://202.70.115.114:90/MailingServices.asmx

Now I create one asp.net website to consume this mailing services.

I create this website in my desktop computer, and add a reference to MailingServices Dev link which is http://192.168.3.17:90/MailingServices.asmx, and then I check in the website to its dev environment, this stage is fine: Website Dev reference Web Services Dev.

But If deploy this website into its production server, how can I change the url link of that web services from its dev link to live link?

I currently know that when the website is deployed to production server, you can over-write the link in web.config file of website, but asp.net generates some other XML files when it add a web service reference, well I can over-write these xml files too.

However, I think this not an easy and appropriate way to complete this whole task, So I come to ask if you guys have anyone suggestion about this?

Many Thanks.

***Edited***
Development Environment:
Server: windows 2008
Web: ASP.NET 3.5/4.0, IIS6.0+
Source Control: VSS 2005, we do not have Automation Build & Continuous Integration

Comment: How are you deploying the site?

Comment: Hi Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi, we deploy the website via using VSS too which is really painful, but I cannot change it.

Comment: BTW, You are the author of 'Inside the Microsoft Build Engine'?! I just received your book today. :)

Comment: Thanks for buying the book. I hope it saves you some time :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to transform your web.config on deploy then I would suggest that you take a look at [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx). With these transformations when you publish from inside of VS the transformations will be automatically run for you, but since it looks like you are not deploying from VS you will need to perform some work to streamline the process. Here is what you need to do conceptually:

1. Build your project
2. Prepare your site for deployment
3. Transform the web.config file
4. Publish your site

For step #3 you can use the TransformXml task that we ship with VS (when you select Web to be installed). Using this task is very easy, here is a sample project which demonstrates this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"
         AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>

  <Target Name="TransformWebConfig">
    <TransformXml Source="some\path\to\the\source\web.config"
                  Transform="some\path\to\the\web.transform.config"
                  Destination="some\path\to\the\dest\web.config" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I've got a bunch of info on using this task on my blog at http://sedodream.com/SearchView.aspx?q=TransformXml.